# How can I open a task pane when I click the send button in outlook web addin - js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I m adding attachments in outlook web addIn
I want to open a new taskpane when I click the send button, how can I do
I want to delete and upload attachments
I can do it very easily on the desktop version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not supported on Outlook web for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

We do not support launching a taskpane via outlook web-addins when sending, however, we do support executing a javascript function during Send, which you can read about over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?view=outlook-js-preview&tabs=classic).

If you want to request for a feature for launching a taskpane, you can do that on our [uservoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). We consider our uservoice requests when going through our planning process.

Just curious, when you say you can do it easily on the desktop version, do you mean with the use of COM based add-ins?

Comment: @ Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, is this feature is incorporated in the outlook add-in opening of taskpane via js?